# Export data using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to export data in excel file.I am using JSON post for the same.Its working fine in every browser except IE. Have a look at my javascript code as follow:-

```
function ExportQueryData() {
            var Qry = $("#txtQueryInput").val();
            if ($.trim(Qry) == "") {
                $("#txtQueryInput").addClass("error");
                return false;
            }
            else
                $("#txtQueryInput").removeClass("error");
            var url = "/Reports/ExportQueryData";
            var frmserialize = $("#frmQuery").serialize();

            $.post(url, frmserialize, function(data) {
                data = eval("(" + data + ")");
                if (data.Success) {
                    url = "/Reports/Export";
                    var win = window.open(url, "DownloadWin", "resizable=0,status=0,toolbar=0,width=600px,height=300px");
                    win.focus();
                    win.moveTo(100, 100);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    Notify("DB Query", data.Message);
                }
            });
        }
```

As per above code, i am calling `/Reports/Export` action using window.open. This pop up getting open for every browser except IE. In IE pop up get close simultaneously in 1 or 2 seconds.
I need to use JSON post because it validate input and then returns success status.I can validate my data only at server side.

Let me know if any information is missing here.
Your suggestion will be valuable for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a pop up blocker situation... Frankly, I don't think opening up stuff in a pop up is a good idea anymore. Browsers seem to hate it.

You could instead show the user a link to the file, asking him to click to download.